# How to enable URL rewrite in 18.04?

Tags: server, apache2, php

Working to install spicecrm, the instance is requesting URL rewrite to be configured. To allow the crm to run I have "downgraded" the php version to 7.1 and removed both 7.0 and 7.2 from Ubuntu 18.04, as the residual configuration was giving me grief.

Now URL rewrite needs to be configured and [digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04) is suggesting to add:

```xml
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        <Directory /var/www/html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
```

to the `000-default.conf` file

On restart the Apache server provides this status output:

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enab
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-09-09 22:56:16 CEST; 19s ago
  Process: 10530 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 7153 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful (code=exited, status=0/SUCCE
  Process: 10574 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 10498 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)


Sep 09 22:56:16 mavezaCRM4 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Sep 09 22:56:16 mavezaCRM4 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code
Sep 09 22:56:16 mavezaCRM4 apachectl[10574]: apache2: Syntax error on line 225 of /e
Sep 09 22:56:16 mavezaCRM4 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-cod
Sep 09 22:56:16 mavezaCRM4 apachectl[10574]: Action 'start' failed.
Sep 09 22:56:16 mavezaCRM4 apachectl[10574]: The Apache error log may have more info
Sep 09 22:56:16 mavezaCRM4 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
lines 1-17/17 (END)
```

I would appreciate any suggestion to what I have missed in the process.

```
$ journalctl -lxeu apache2.service
-- Unit apache2.service has finished reloading its configuration
--
-- The result is RESULT.
Sep 10 20:02:12 mavezaCRM4 systemd[1]: Stopping The Apache HTTP Server...
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has begun shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit apache2.service has begun shutting down.
Sep 10 20:02:12 mavezaCRM4 apachectl[15171]: apache2: Syntax error on line 225 o
Sep 10 20:02:12 mavezaCRM4 apachectl[15171]: Action 'stop' failed.
Sep 10 20:02:12 mavezaCRM4 apachectl[15171]: The Apache error log may have more
Sep 10 20:02:12 mavezaCRM4 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited,
Sep 10 20:02:12 mavezaCRM4 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit
Sep 10 20:02:12 mavezaCRM4 systemd[1]: Stopped The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support  
--
-- Unit apache2.service has finished shutting down.
Sep 10 20:02:12 mavezaCRM4 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit apache2.service has begun starting up.
Sep 10 20:02:12 mavezaCRM4 apachectl[15176]: apache2: Syntax error on line 225 o
Sep 10 20:02:12 mavezaCRM4 apachectl[15176]: Action 'start' failed.
Sep 10 20:02:12 mavezaCRM4 apachectl[15176]: The Apache error log may have more
Sep 10 20:02:12 mavezaCRM4 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited,
Sep 10 20:02:12 mavezaCRM4 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit
Sep 10 20:02:12 mavezaCRM4 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit apache2.service has failed.
--
-- The result is RESULT.
lines 615-653/653 (END)
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `journalctl -lxeu apache2.service`? It should include the complete path of the configuration file with the syntax error. Then please also include (a link to) the affected file in your question. Thanks.

Comment: Hi David, Please find the output added to the question, your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you really supply the `-l` option to `journalctl`? If you did it shouldn’t normally shorten the lines of the log output. You can add the `--no-pager` to avoid other possible sources of horizontal elision. On another note it looks like you forgot to add the link to the instructions that you followed and led to the current situation.

Comment: Hi @David, sorry for the dela. This is the exact comment I used: "journalctl -lxeu apache2.service". The digital Ocean page is the following: [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: Could you please try again with `journalctl --no-pager -lxeu apache2.service`? Please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Answer edited out of the question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1073765/revisions):

> @David: with your guidance and the `--no-pager` switch in the `journalctl` command, I have found the culprit(s). One stupidity, in trying to make things work I lost a `/` in front of the closing Directory command. Then there was a new complaint on determining the server's fully qualified server name (fixed by adding a `.conf` file to the `conf-available` directory and activate it with `a2enconf`). At this point I had a clean start of Apache2. The followed the Digital Ocean protocol by adding a `.htaccess` file to the web-root, with the command `RewriteEngine on`. All is now running!